# How do you organise scientific articles with and without annotations?

Tags: software, review-articles

Like most of you, I read several scientific articles every week and annotate them on my tablet.

Do you know of a useful way to organise "clean" vs "annotated" articles in a way that is searchable and mobile-device friendly?

I use Papers now, but it isn't useful to have two copies of everything: a clean one and an annotated one.

Maybe one of you guys have a brilliant method to deal with this.

Comment: Wouldn't be a better question how to hide annotations?

Comment: Nope. I like the annotations there (but for myself only, so I store two versions...

Comment: What OS do you use?

Comment: iOS exclusively

Comment: "Like most of you, [...] and annotate them on my tablet":  Many people don't annotate articles, and probably a lot more don't even use tablets (I'm one who neither annotates articles nor use tablets, and I know many others who don't do it either).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [Mendeley](https://www.mendeley.com)

This should cover nearly all your requirements -- with or without annotation.

Although my personal choice would be [**BibDesk**](http://bibdesk.sourceforge.net) (which I use nearly every day), Mendeley hits it for a cross-platform mobile-friendly experience.